# Generate secure token for external api Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, encryption, jwt, ruby-on-rails-5

I have to apps that need to communicate with each other in this way:

- Service 1 communicates to Service 2 that it needs to create a new user and a token for that user.
- Service 2 verifies it is really Service 1 making the request
- Service 2 generates the token for the user to use

I'm not sure what would be the 'best/better' way to verify that Service 1 is making the request.
As of now I'm generating tokens for the users with the JWT gem, and have been using this in development to generate a secret key for Service 1.

```
payload =  {data: 'admin'}
admin_key = JWT.encode(payload,Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)
```

I give the key to Service 1 to send and then decode it and check if it's what I originally sent

```
def authorize_admin
    payload = request.headers['Authorization']
    raise(ExceptionHandler::MissingToken, Message.missing_token) if payload.blank?
    body = JWT.decode(payload, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base)[0].values
    body.include?('admin')
end
```

This works, but I'm concerned that this may not be a secure option, or what alternatives there might be that can improve this.  The `Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base` is unique to my application so I thought that this would be suitable to use to encrypt the token with JWT.

To sum up, my questions:

1. What can I use in my rails application to verify another external app?
2. Is JWT in conjunction with the secret_key_base a secure way to create a unique token for an external api?

I've checked through some other posts about JWT, but none (that I found) went into specifics about its use along with the secret_key_base in a rails app

Comment: Just one idea. But better get the opinion of more experienced developer. Generate a set of tokens (`SecureRandom.base58`) and store it in a table of the Service1. Service2 must send the token as parameter to identify itself. If the token exist in the database, then allow transactions. From time to time Service2 requires a new set of tokens, old sets expires. A token of the set can not be used twice in a row.

Comment: I like this idea, I wasn't sure how to go about changing the token, I can't set it to simply expire, because then there would be no access, your idea seems like a good workaround

Answer (score 0):

JWT is signing the payload with the secret key instead of encrypted it. A signature is not inherently secure because given an input, it will always return the same output (i.e. a pattern for the signature begins to emerge). For maximum security, you would want to opt for encryption using AES-256 (or higher) for the payload.

Also in this case, the authorization header will always be the same since you're sending the same payload encoded with the same key, meaning I can hit server 2 from my own site with the same header and get back a user and token. It depends how sensitive service 2 is, if it's open to everyone to create users then it doesn't really matter. Otherwise that can be a huge security concern.

How are the two servers decoupled? If service 2 has a limited number of other services to interact with and it knows what they are, you could use a CORS header to ensure only service 1 can receive requests from service 2.

Comment: If I know the endpoint and the authorization header, I can send requests to service 2 from any location right? Either from my own site, curl, etc

Comment: Yes, as it is now, if you have the endpoint and a token to put in the authorization header you can access the service.  What I want to do is only allow one user (service 1)  access to the  create user functions (store email, name in database and generate tokens for the users to use when accessing service 2). I basically have one service that is responsible for creating and managing users for the other service, which is an api for validating phone and address data.

Comment: If those services have access to the same DB, maybe you can have an "admin" token (some random secret key) that gets re-generated and stored every few hours. Service 1 encrypts that token in the header and service 2 decrypts and confirms the token is in the db and is valid. You might also want to add another safeguard in service 2 to make sure the request url is from service 1 and reject all other traffic.